# How to create a m3u8 Byte-Range playlist without creating a new file

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I've found some nice related questions,such as this one [How to create byte-range m3u8 playlist for HLS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23497782/how-to-create-byte-range-m3u8-playlist-for-hls) but the best answer, that provide us this ffmpeg command `ffmpeg -i sample.ts -hls_time 20 -hls_flags single_file out.m3u8` creates a new .ts file to use in the m3u8. In my application we need to create the m3u8 file, but we want it to be faster than the solution provided, it was unworkable for us. I think that the provided solution is a little slow 'cause it has to create a new file, do you guys know a solution that uses a already existing encoded ts file?

Comment: This appeases to be an X Y question as It is HIGHLY unlikely file creation is a bottleneck. What exactly is too slow?

Comment: First, thanks for the reply. 
It took 30 seconds to create the .m3u8 file, but created the .ts file since the beginning and worked on it till the end (1min and 7 seconds), when it reached 30 seconds, both files were modified dinamically till the end of the execution. I used a 40MB .ts file with 50 seconds of video on it.

Comment: If you give ios an m3u8 with only one file in a live manifest, it will error out. So ffmpeg will not write the manifest until there is enough video to make it a legal playlist.

Comment: ok, man, I'm sorry, just noticed an error that i did trying to explain my problem. I think that the problem is the processing of the new file. I want a command that uses a already existing file, so, there'll be no need to write a new ts file (the new file created in the ffmpeg command had 69mb, the original one had 40mb). So, if there is a command that creates a m3u8 byteranged file based on a existing ts file, it'll be perfect for me

Answer (score 1):

Your command is slow because it re-encodes the whole input video. Just add `-c copy` option. Since the input is already a .ts file, there's no need to re-encode it.

Comment: Thank you, sir! It's exactly what i wanted, the command ran in 0.2 seconds when I added `-c copy'!